# String new line (trying to connect java to Oracle DB)

Tags: java, string, oracle, newline

I'm connecting Java to Oracle database, everything's is going pretty okay, except the following problem:

This works okay when I write the whole string within one couple of quotes:

```
String command =
     "SELECT FIRST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE SALARY < 5000";
```

BUT as the one above doesn't look well-designed code I wanted to split the lines:

```
String command = new StringBuilder(
    "SELECT FIRST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, SALARY\n")
            .append("FROM EMPLOYEES\n")
            .append("WHERE SALARY < 5000;")
            .toString();
```

And meanwhile, I tried plus (+) instead of StringBuilder, but again messed up...

Please help((

Comment: Using the StringBuilder like this is a lot more inefficient that diretly writing the String literal or using `+`

Comment: You dont need a string builder for this ... your first line is the right way to do it for string literals.

Comment: Why are there newlines within the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using StringBuilder.append() for a constant value is less efficient than writing the constant directly:

```
String command =
     "SELECT FIRST_NAME, " + 
     "       PHONE_NUMBER, \n " + 
     "       SALARY \n " + 
     "FROM EMPLOYEES \n" + 
     "WHERE SALARY < 5000";
```

Comment: Why newlines within the query?

Comment: That's what Emil asked for (they do not change the result of the SQL in any way and are not needed...)

Answer (score 2):

```
String command = new StringBuilder(
    "SELECT FIRST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, SALARY  ")
            .append("FROM EMPLOYEES  ")
            .append("WHERE SALARY < 5000")
            .toString();
```

Comment: Remove that semi-colon from the end of query.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have modified that

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,

Why use newline character [\n] which is not understood by sql engines?

It should work without it